# When to use the "new-parents" tag?

Tags: discussion

How can I decide when it would be correct to use the "new-parents" tag?

Comment: Do you mean the "new-parents" tag, or the new "parents" tag? (The "parents" tag is not new...)

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun I meant "new-parents" tag. :)

Comment: Sounds like a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), which are generally discouraged.  In particular, it sounds an awful lot like a `beginner` tag.

Comment: Thanks - I took the liberty of editing your question a little to make it clear. You can edit it again if you disagree with my change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *parents* tag has this description:

> About the parents themselves, and not (only) about the children.

So when your question relates to parents more than to the child, use the tag.

The *new-parents* tag doesn't have a description and, in my mind, doesn't make a lot of sense. Either the topic relates to the *parents* (see above), or it relates to the child, in which case no "parent" tag should be applied but rather one of the age-bracket tags like *infant, toddler, pre-schooler* etc.

I think we should remove the *new-parents* tag.

Comment: The parents tag usage is obvious, I was referring to the other one. I too think the other tag is somewhat useless with the major tags like infant, toddler, parents etc around.

Comment: so, finally, who will decide whether the tag will be deleted or not?

Comment: @user462608 Normally, the process is to wait until there's a consensus on meta. Given our general levels of participation, and the very small usage of the tag, I'm going to go ahead and remove the tag (and replace it with the [tag:parents] where appropriate.

Comment: Agreed, new-parents tag should probably go.